# Oasis build configuration with subdirectories

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I am using oasis to build my ocaml project, with the source code present in a directory called src. The oasis build file looks like that:

```
OASISFormat: 0.4
Name:        Test
Version:     0.1
Synopsis:    no
Authors:     Me
License:     BSD-3-clause
Plugins:     META (0.4)

Executable abc
  Path:        src
  BuildTools:  ocamlbuild
  MainIs:      main.ml
```

Now I would like to organize the files into subfolders, putting a.mli and a.ml into src/util. After doing this, the module becomes invisible to ocamlbuild/ocamlc, resulting in an 'unbound module A' error. If I would call ocamlc by hand, I can add the -I src/util flag to make a.mli visible again.

How can I add the additional paths to the oasis configuration without making the files full libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible with oasis, you need to modify your `_tags` file, but I wouldn't advice you to do this. The general approach is to create `Library` entries in your oasis file. This helps to keep your project structure clean. And if you wouldn't like to create a library from utils, then why bother and move it into a subfolder.

Comment: To me, a library is for code reuse - i.e. it is general enough to be needed in a different project. But it is still useful to divide different parts of a project by clean interfaces even if the parts are not to be used on their own. Making them a library (in the sense of its own .cma file) seems overkill to me.

Answer (score 3):

You may try to add `<src/utils>: include` to your `_tags` file (this file is generated by oasis, you cannot edit it anyware: do it outside the scope of the generated part.

This will directly tell ocamlbuild to add a -I src/utils to its arguments, I don't think it's possible to tell oasis to do this himself without making a library.